# Von Mangoldt function with PARI GP

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, programming

How to program the Von Mangoldt function:
$$\Lambda (n)=\begin{cases}\log p&{\text{if }}n=p^{k}{\text{ for some prime }}p{\text{ and integer }}k\geq 1,\\0&{\text{otherwise.}}\end{cases}$$

with PARI/GP.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementation for the function in Pari/GP:

```
Mangoldt(n)={ispower(n,,&n);if(isprime(n),log(n),0)};
```

For the exponential of Mangoldt function [A014963](https://oeis.org/A014963) type:

```
A014963(n)={round(exp(Mangoldt(n)))};
```